# How do I decide over my expected salary that I can ask my employer while I'm hired as permanent employee?

Tags: salary, contractors

I was hired as temporary employee to X company by a contracting agency. I was given a hike of 60% while I joined as contractor and its hardly six months since I had joined the X company my manager from X company wants me to be a permanent employee.

As a part of Contractor to Hire process, I'm asked to fill out my expected salary. Given a 60% hike just six months back, is it fine to expect a hike while converting as permanent employee? How can I decide over the percentage of hike I can put in the expected salary column?

Comment: Does the contracting company provide benefits? Will the new company provide benefits.? How will those benefits differ?

Comment: Contracting company don't give any benefits. New company have benefits, its one of a reputed organisation in the country I live. As I said since the contracting company don't give me any benefits my pay is almost exactly whats show in the CTC. I'm skeptic about new company where CTC would reflect benefits which reduces my on hand salary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Given a 60% hike just six months back, is it fine to expect a hike
>   while converting as permanent employee? How can I decide over the
>   percentage of hike I can put in the expected salary column ?

You salary expectations for a permanent position should have no relation to your pay as a temp.

Decide what you need for salary and benefits to make this permanent job worthwhile to you for the long haul. Consider what you could expect to get elsewhere as a permanent (not temporary) employee.